# how does google docs read powerpoint files?

Tags: web-applications, powerpoint, google-docs

I'm designing a webapp for my uni and I need to be able to read some powerpoint files ... Does anyone know what's the best way to access powerpoint files and read the data in a web friendly way ?

Comment: php on apache and for front side (although I dont think it matters) I use jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "best" answer for this, the older PowerPoint formats are proprietary, although are documented here: [Microsoft's Site](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx).

I guess your only way would be to write a server-side script to open the files and try and grab the bits you want. There is also a Java library to access PowerPoint files called [POI](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html).

In any case, there's no "easy" solution for this. Google will probably have their own implementation of a PowerPoint "reader", then convert the files in the background to their own format after you upload them. In a similar vein, your best bet is probably going to be to do something similar, upload the files, process them into a more sensible format yourself, then emit them on the web page.